# Some table's rows should remain with same width and the others don't

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table with some trs.

There are some tr-s that are visible and the other are invisible.

The tr-s that are visible in init, we will call: `mainTrs`.

When clicking on tr that is visible, all the tr-s that has a class with its id, will be visible.

When clicking it again, all the tr-s that were opened, will be close.

When invisible becomes visible, the table "jumps".

I want the `mainTrs` to stay with the same width of its td-s..

(And the others tr-s to open as they open).

---

**For example:**

in Init, assuming this is the table:

[image]

Now, these rows should stay with the same width when toggling.

---

**Good results:**

[image]

[image]

As you see, the rows from init (red and blue) remains with the same width.

The others rows became bigger, but without affecting the blue and red trs.

---

**Bad results:**

[image]

[image]

It's bad because the red and blue rows are more bigger than initialized.

---

I've tried to use max-width for the `mainTrs` but with no success.

---

This is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr id="a123" onclick="toggleTable(this)" data-isOpen="false">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a123 hidden">
        <td>this is my first cell</td>
        <td>this is my second cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a123 hidden">
        <td>another text</td>
        <td>another text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="a456" onclick="toggleTable(this)" data-isOpen="false">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a456 hidden">
        <td>wow</td>
        <td>more text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a456 hidden">
        <td>something</td>
        <td>sometimes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function toggleTable(element) {
    var isNeedToShowMore = $(element).attr('data-isOpen') == "false";
    $(element).attr('data-isOpen', isNeedToShowMore);

    var elementId = $(element).attr('id');
    if (isNeedToShowMore) {
        $('tr.tr_' + elementId).show();
    }
    else {
        $('tr.tr_' + elementId).hide();
    }
}
```

And this is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/52kj3b8m/

Comment: You get spaces like that because you are using a `<table>` . Table columns will take on the size of the largest content, so if every cell's width is the same as the cell above and below it, you'll get that type of spacing you find undesirable. To understand better of what I mean, add borders to the `<td>` The results of what you want could be achieved by using accordions.

Comment: You can make it as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You get spaces like that because you are using a `<table>`. Table columns will take on the size of the largest content, so if every cell's width is the same as the cell above and below it, you'll get that type of spacing you find undesirable. To understand better of what I mean, add borders to the `<td>`. The results of what you want could be achieved by using accordions.

Snippet 1 illustrates the reason you are getting undesirable presentation of content.

Snippet 2 is an accordion, keep in mind this demonstration utilizes [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js), [jQuery UI](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js), and [Dark Hive theme](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css).

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
function toggleTable(element) {
    var isNeedToShowMore = $(element).attr('data-isOpen') == "false";
    $(element).attr('data-isOpen', isNeedToShowMore);

    var elementId = $(element).attr('id');
    if (isNeedToShowMore) {
        $('tr.tr_' + elementId).show();
    }
    else {
        $('tr.tr_' + elementId).hide();
    }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="a123" onclick="toggleTable(this)" data-isOpen="false">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a123 hidden">
        <td>this is my first cell</td>
        <td>this is my second cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a123 hidden">
        <td>another text</td>
        <td>another text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="a456" onclick="toggleTable(this)" data-isOpen="false">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a456 hidden">
        <td>wow</td>
        <td>more text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_a456 hidden">
        <td>something</td>
        <td>sometimes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Accordions</title>
  <link href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    d
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>
  <main>
    <section class='rows'>
      <dl>
        <dt>Header 1</dt>
        <dd>
          <p>
            Yoggothog mg f'athg ep hrii orr'e 'fhalma hafh'drn phlegeth, nglui ron phlegeth mnahn' throd 'fhalma chtenff R'lyeh bug, Chaugnar Faugnnyth nog hai nw ebunma llll 'ai naYoggoth, grah'noth nwagl ph'hlirgh nog syha'h Yoggoth cya. Ch' namnahn' f'li'hee uaaah
            'fhalma Nyarlathotepog 'fhalma r'luh ya shugg vulgtlagln, y'hah ngfhtagn n'ghft y-fm'latgh k'yarnak hafh'drn Cthulhu llll. Shtunggli ftaghu Chaugnar Faugn uaaah nog kadishtu lw'nafh mg ehye y'hah goka, y-ee gokaoth hupadgh nalw'nafh zhro orr'e
            shugg stell'bsna ph''ai, geb nnnch' li'hee grah'nnyth cr'luh Azathoth kadishtu y-n'gha nnngnaiih. Cphlegeth orr'e 'bthnk Nyarlathotep shagg shugg ph'Azathoth nggeb stell'bsna, cthrod shogg n'gha zhro sgn'wahl orr'e shogg sgn'wahl, nnnhai shugg
            goka k'yarnak fhtagnnyth uh'e Shub-Niggurath.
          </p>
          <p>
            Zhro fhtagn Nyarlathotep n'gha 'bthnk geb ftaghu gotha tharanaknyth f''fhalma grah'n, f'ilyaa naflshtunggli nnnchtenff ebunma gof'nn fm'latghyar mnahn' Tsathoggua y-shugg. Tharanak uln h'stell'bsna n'ghaog naflli'hee shtunggli h'Cthulhu geb shogg ch',
            ph'gnaiih wgah'n ngshogg y'hah r'luhyar orr'e ftaghu wgah'n, h'shugg shoggnyth syha'h wgah'n navulgtm nak'yarnak geb stell'bsna. Gof'nn uh'e ngk'yarnak sll'ha Hastur fm'latgh Yoggoth naflnglui ilyaaagl, hlirgh li'hee tharanak Yoggoth ilyaa
            Yoggoth ya, ch' nilgh'ri orr'eog f'sgn'wahl nglui ilyaa goka. Vulgtlagln ep sll'hanyth n'ghft shogg mg naflhupadgh cnog, ph'mg grah'nyar nw grah'n 'bthnk 'ai uaaah ngvulgtlagln, chtenff nnnfm'latgh 'bthnk ch' hrii vulgtm.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lloig nog zhro 'bthnk R'lyeh 'fhalma nglui sll'ha uln, bug Yoggoth epyar stell'bsna shugg ebunma nnnorr'e, chrii h'syha'h sll'ha lloig f'wgah'n ph'gotha hlirgh. Sgn'wahl syha'h y-ehye fm'latgh vulgtlagln h'nog naflehye mg Azathoth naorr'e nnnhafh'drn,
            naflChaugnar Faugn y-hrii wgah'n naep 'fhalma Azathoth wgah'n naflr'luh ilyaa ooboshu Nyarlathotep, h'Tsathoggua Shub-Niggurath y-hai mg lw'nafh Nyarlathotep uh'e cron nahupadgh.
          </p>
        </dd>

        <dt>Header 2</dt>
        <dd>
          <iframe id='ifrm1' name='ifrm1' src='http://w3schools.com' width='90%'></iframe>
        </dd>

        <dt>Header 3</dt>
        <dd>
          <video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" width='500' controls></video>
        </dd>

      </dl>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.rows').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        header: 'dt',
        heightStyle: 'content',
        active: false
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```